# Table width with internal style sheet

Tags: css, html

I'm using an external CSS file that specifies a standard **table** `width`, but I have one table that I want to make smaller. How do I write an internal CSS file to specify this?

Answer (score 2):

You can define "inline style" like this for that table

`<table style="width:200px">`

or you can place Style inside `<head></head>` tag.

ex :

```
<head>  
  <style type="text/css">
    #any_id_for_table{width:200px !important;} 
  </style>
</head>

<body>  
   <table id="any_id_for_table"> .... </table> 
</body>
```

NOTE: (Adding a **!important** will over ride any CSS defined elsewhere.)

Answer (score 0):

I would put an id or class on the table and specify a style targeting that particular element instead of relying on a gloabal table css style

Alternatively you can override with an inline style on that particular table

Comment: he wants **one** table smaller

Answer (score 0):

you can place one in the `<head>` of said document. or just add the style sheet later in the document if you wish.

but what you want is to assign the table with `id="smaller"`and add css rules for that (even in the external style sheet). because you want specifically one table as smaller.

Answer (score 0):

Within your head tag add

```
<style>
table
{
    // style goes here. eg: width: 100px;
}
</style>
```

If it is not working try adding !important with the style. eg: `width: 100px !important;`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this type of css

```
table.smaller{
 width:100px !important;
}
```

HTML

```
  <table class="smaller">
    </table>
```

This will work fine.